# Cross compiled app linking with wrong library?

Tags: linker, compiler-errors, linker-errors, cross-compiling

Trying to keep the background short: I'm working on a very large C++ application which compiles just fine using mostly the libraries that come on 32bit Ubuntu server 12.04 with a few exceptions: libsdl1.2-dev, libedit-dev, and uuid-dev (installed with apt-get). Our build system wraps/hides most of the output unless there is an error.

I'm trying to use a toolchain to cross compile the app for a different OS. The host build machine is the Ubuntu 12.04 and the target OS is an in-house linux OS. The toolchain contains most standard linux libraries so, for the ones that are missing (like libedit and libSDL), I'm cheating (for now) by just creating soft links in the toolchain to point to the ones on the Ubuntu machine.

The cross-compiled app was failing at the linker stage (ld) with this error:

```
<toolchain>/bin/ld: warning: libbsd.so.0, needed by <toolchain>/lib/libedit.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

...so I ran 'ldd' on the non-cross-compiled binary to find the libbsd, then just did

```
ln -s /lib/libbsd.so.0 <toolchain>/lib/libbsd.so.0
```

I've done this for a few different libraries to get past the errors.

The problem: now my cheating is backfiring, I'm seeing:

```
blah.cpp:46: more undefined references to `__stack_chk_guard' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea where to start looking, or what tools will be useful in debugging this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't link against a library compiled for a different architecture or system.  Your only choice is to cross-compile the missing libraries for your target.  No cheating!

Comment: Looks like you have some extra compiler flags for your application that weren't used when building other libraries or the toolchain's standard libs. `__stack_chk_guard` belongs to [GCC's stack smashing protector](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Stack_Smashing_Protector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added the `-lssp` linker flag and everything was cleared up!